# Java ArrayList Copy Changing Original Value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have copied an `ArrayList` as I want to keep original values of my source `Arraylist`.

If I change first item of my source `ArrayList`, it automatically changes first item value of new `ArrayList`.

I used a few code blocks but I couldn't solve this problem.

```
ArrayList<SicilBakiye> resultCopy = new ArrayList<SicilBakiye>();
resultCopy.addAll(result);  // 1.method

resultCopy=result.clone();  // 2.method

resultCopy=result;  // 3.method
```

If I change :

```
result.get(0).setid(5);
```

This automatically changes :

```
resultCopy.get(0).getid() // return 5
```

How can I solve ? Thanks for your ideas

Comment: Your 1. method was really close. You need to add copies of the original entries. Otherwise they will be the same.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795199

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep clone an object list that contains several objects in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795199/how-to-deep-clone-an-object-list-that-contains-several-objects-in-java)

Comment: @AkshayBhat this is List but I use ArrayList

Comment: ArrayList implements List, so you can use List.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a look at the 3 methods you provided and then address your problem:

> ArrayList resultCopy = new ArrayList();
>   
> resultCopy.addAll(result);  // 1.method

This creates an empty array list and adds all elements from `result` to the copy. Any change to `result` itself (e.g. adding a new element or removing one) is *not* reflected in the copy.

> resultCopy=result.clone();  // 2.method

That basically does the same as above, at least of the standard implementation is used - just that the copy is created inside of `clone()` and then returned.

> resultCopy=result;  // 3.method

This just assigns the instance that `result` references to `resultCopy`, i.e. you have 2 references to the same list. Thus any change made to `result` is reflected by `resultCopy` and vice versa.

Now to your actual problem:

`result.get(0).setid(5);` *does not* change `result` but the element *inside* `result`. Thus you also see that change in `resultCopy`.

It's the same as if I put you into two courses at school. If you leave one you'll still be in the other and vice versa. But if your age changes (which it will ;) ) the teacher in each course will get the same answer.

What you're probably after is called a deep copy: you copy the list as well as the elements inside the list. If those reference other objects you might have to copy them as well - where to stop depends on your requirements and the structure of your objects.

To create deep copies of your objects you could either implement and call `clone()` where needed, use a library that clones via reflection (e.g. Apache Commons BeanUtils)  or use a mapping library (e.g. Dozer, Mapstruct, etc.).

Comment: for 3.method: already change resultCopy. Not result.  
for 1.method: reflected copy. You can try.

Comment: @mobileprogramming I'm not sure what you mean by that. `resultCopy=result;` will make both variables reference the exact same list.

Comment: OK. How can I keep values of Copy ArrayList? Which method may I use ?

Comment: @mobileprogramming read my last two paragraphs. Those should contain what you want (at least what I guess you want).

Comment: for(SicilBakiye bakiye : result) {
    resultCopy.add(bakiye.clone());
   }
 I wrote this block but clone method is wrong. Warning message : "clone() has protected access in Java.lang.object"

Comment: @mobileprogramming you should read the JavaDoc and maybe some tutorials on `clone()`. Your object would have to implement `Cloneable()` and probably would also have to provide an implementation of `clone()` instead of relying on the default implementation of `clone()`.

Comment: okey I solved. I use this code: 
  
                         'for(SicilBakiye bakiye : result) {
    resultCopy.add((SicilBakiye) bakiye.clone());
   }' 
and 
'SicilBakiye implements Cloneable{ 
 .....
public SicilBakiye clone() {
  try {
   return (SicilBakiye) super.clone();
  } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw new RuntimeException();
  }
 }'

Answer (score 0):

`clone()` creates a shallow copy. Which means the elements will not be cloned. (What if they didn't implement Cloneable?)

You may want to use `Arrays.copyOf(..)` for copying arrays instead of `clone()` (though cloning is fine for arrays, unlike for anything else)

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance/2156367#2156367)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a "deep copy" of the ArrayList.  That is you need to copy (clone) each of the objects in the list.

When you do a shallow copy of the ArrayList your second ArrayList is pointing to the same objects as the original.

```
ArrayList<SicilBakiye> resultCopy = new ArrayList<SicilBakiye>();
for (SicilBakiye obj : original) {
    resultCopy.add((SicilBakiye)obj.clone());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okey I solved. I use this code:

```
  for(SicilBakiye bakiye : result) {
            resultCopy.add((SicilBakiye) bakiye.clone());
        }
```

and

```
SicilBakiye implements Cloneable{ 
    .....
public SicilBakiye clone() {
        try {
            return (SicilBakiye) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's more of a side note but from my experience it's best to either throw an exception (in your case you could do `throw new RuntimeException(e)`) or handle it (e.g. by logging it). Doing both can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Below example will helps to others if changing any value in clone ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> arrayListObject = new ArrayList<>();

arrayListObject.add("A");
arrayListObject.add("B");
arrayListObject.add("C");
arrayListObject.add("D");

System.out.println("Original Arraylist Values::" + arrayListObject);

ArrayList<String> arrayListClone = (ArrayList<String>) arrayListObject.clone();
System.out.println("Clone Arraylist Values::" + arrayListClone);

System.out.println("After changed position at 0 index in Clone Arraylist");
arrayListClone.set(0, "AA");

System.out.println("Original Arraylist Values::" + arrayListObject);
System.out.println("Clone Arraylist Changed Values::" + arrayListClone);
```

**Output**

```
Original Arraylist Values::[A, B, C, D]
Clone Arraylist Values::[A, B, C, D]

After changed position at 0 index in Clone Arraylist
Original Arraylist Values::[A, B, C, D]
Clone Arraylist Changed Values::[AA, B, C, D]
```